# Effective aperture as a function of Azimuth and Elevation Angle

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, antennas

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_(antenna))

The effective aperture of an antenna is given by $$A_{\mathrm{e}}(\theta, \phi)=\eta A \cos \theta \cos \phi ,$$

where, $(\theta, \phi)$ are the azimuth and elevation angles relative to the array normal, $\eta$ is the radiation efficiency, $A$ is the physical aperture area of the antenna.

My confusion is based on the fact that Effective aperture of an isotropic antenna is also given by

$$A_e =\frac{\lambda^2}{4\pi}.$$

I am unable to connect between these two formulae. I know second is specific for isotropic antenna, but there should be a way to go from first formula to the second using some conditions. I am unable to identify that.  Can someone help me establish how to go from the first equation to the second.

Comment: [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/86160/73458) derivation might help.

Comment: @Obliv, I have seen it. My issue is how can I link the two seemingly different equations.

Comment: they are unrelated. The 1st eq. assumes a "flat" emitter of geometric aperture $A$,  say, a horn, whose efficiency is $\eta$ so the effective aperture is $\eta A$ and multiplied with $\cos \theta \cos \phi$ you get the effective area looking it at from a side viewing angle. The isotropic emitter has spherical symmetry and has  the same emissivity from all angles.

Comment: @hyportnex, But the Wikipedia article is talking for any antenna, right ? I thought it's a general statement that should hold for any antenna type.

Comment: for an arbitrary antenna and for arbitrarily large angles, not just near the axis, i.e., small $\theta, \phi$,  you have to take into account diffraction effects (sidelobes and some such), $A_e = \eta D(\theta, \phi) \frac{\lambda^2}{4\pi}$ where $D(\theta , \phi)$ is the *directivity* of the antenna. For example, a linear dipole is axially symmetric, and thus its directivity and effective aperture are independent of the azimuth angle $\phi$, and depend only on the elevation angle $\theta$.

Comment: Thank u :) @hyportnex